# images in android 4.4 inside a WebView turns to a blurry image

Tags: java, android, webview, chromium

I have `WebView` inside a `LinearLayout`. My `WebView` shows a local HTML file that contains an image. In fact, when user runs my app, sees an image inside a `WebView`, it works fine.

But I have a problem. I put a scale animation to the parent `LinearLayout` that scales from a little box to real size in 400ms. In this case my image turns to a blurry image ONLY IN ANDROID 4.4 KITKAT. In this version of android, `WebView` uses chrome engine and i think chrome in the first milliseconds of running of App sets a size to my image, and then after animation,  it's like that I scale a small image to a very big image. It turns blurry. How can I make sure that chrome does not set the image size in the initialization. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example of code used to apply the animation and I'll try to recreate it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. The code isn't anything special. It's just a WebView. If you scale it down, and then scale it up, the entire thing gets blurry.